# Array type erasure

Tags: java, generics

Why the following code is potentially not type-safe (the compiler generates a warning)?

```
class ArrayTypeErasure<T> {
    private T[] elements;

    public void setElements(List<T> elements) {
        this.elements = (T[]) elements.toArray();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to think of any situations when the code would fail, but so far it's only me who is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that arrays know their component type at runtime, but instances of generic classes don't know the generic type argument at runtime. A `List<T>` cannot create an array object at runtime with the runtime type of `T[]` without further information, since it doesn't know what `T` is at runtime. The `List#toArray()` method that takes one array parameter, uses the runtime type of the passed-in array instance to construct an array of the same component type at runtime. But the `List#toArray()` with no parameters always creates an array with the runtime type `Object[]`. So `elements.toArray()` evaluates to an array instance that always has the runtime type of `Object[]`.

`Object[]` is not a subtype of `T[]` (when `T` is not `Object`), so assigning this array to `this.elements`, of compile-time type `T[]`, is wrong. However, it doesn't immediately cause any exceptions, since the erasure of `T` is `Object`, so the erasure of `T[]` is `Object[]`, and assigning `Object[]` to `Object[]` is fine. It won't cause any issues as long as you make sure to never expose the object contained in `this.elements` to outside this object as `T[]`. However, if you expose the object contained in `this.elements` as type `T[]` to outside the class (e.g. a method that returns `this.elements` as type `T[]`, or if you make `this.elements` a public or protected field), a caller outside the class might expect `T` to be a specific type, and that can cause a class cast exception.

For example, if you have a method that returns `this.elements` as type `T[]`:

```
public T[] getElements() {
    return this.elements;
}
```

and then you have a caller that holds `ArrayTypeErasure<String>` and it calls `.getElements()` on it, it will expect a `String[]`. When it tries to assign the result to a `String[]`, it will cause a class cast exception, since the runtime type of the object is `Object[]`:

```
ArrayTypeErasure<String> foo = ...
String[] bar = foo.getElements();
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply because `List#toArray()` returns an `Object[]` so there is no guarantee from this method that it would return `T[]`

Now, in practice, it's ok since you always know that it will return the wanted type

You could use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to avoid this warning from appearing

Comment: Closing questions as duplicates doesn't hurt, there is no need to answer such quesions again.

Comment: so you mean the `elements` array can somehow be rewritten, say from `List<String>[]` originally to `List<Integer>[]`, but the passed list would still contain elements of `List<String>[]`?

Answer (score -2):

Due to type erasure, you can cast `List<X>`s  to `List<Y>`s.

```
ArrayTypeErasure<String> er = new ArrayTypeErasure<>();
ArrayTypeErasure erased = er;
List intList = new List<Integer>();  // compile warnings, but
intList.add(1);
erased.setElements(intList);
```

Comment: Fooling around with raw types is no real argument here. Its like saying "everything in Java is broken and insecure, because reflection exists".

Comment: @Tom He asked for a situation in which it failed, I provided one. Both generic array creation and raw types are rooted in type erasure, so there's no reason not to bring it up.

Comment: You're right that this can be an issue, but of a different scope and compilers (or IDEs) don't generate warnings for the usage of generic types, because someone could ignore them. Thus this doesn't explain why OP still gets a warning for `(T[]) elements.toArray()` and if that really could fail. And your example doesn't explain how the array creation could fail. Your code fails _after_ the array was created and then wrongly used, by deactivating type checks.

Comment: @Tom `List#toArray`works fine, the array creation will never fail. It's always the cast that is the issue here.